# When non of the options are selected for the checkboxes, how to make the value none?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, if-statement, checkbox

I've my code below and I'm using an array here. I'm trying to print "None" value when none of the options are selected, but instead when I submit the form I have a few checkboxes selected; it still says "None". Without the else if condition when I choose to not select one of the option, then I get nothing for the result.

I'm not supposed to create a "None" option for the input function.

```js
function calculatePrice() {
  var array = [];
  var extras = document.calc.extras;

  for (count = 0; count < extras.length; count++) {
    if (extras[count].checked == true) {
      array.push(extras[count].value);
    } else if (!extras[count].checked) {
      array = ["None"];
    }
  }
  alert("(Including extras: " + array + ")");
}
```

```html
<form name="calc">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="40" id="col">
        <label for="extras">EXTRAS</label>
        <div class="left">
          <input type="checkbox" name="extras" id="ac" value="A/C">A/C (+$10)
          <input type="checkbox" name="extras" id="work" value="Working Brakes">Working Brakes (+$100)<br>
          <input type="checkbox" name="extras" id="cruise" value="Cruise Control">Cruise control (+$20)
          <input type="checkbox" name="extras" id="seat" value="Baby Seat">Baby Seat (+$30)<br>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="40" id="col">
        <input type="submit" onClick="calculatePrice();" value="Estimate Cost">
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're replacing `array` with `["None"]` every time there's an empty checkbox, not if *all* of the checkboxes are empty.

The simplest fix is to check after the loop if `array` is empty, e.g.:

```
for (count = 0; count < extras.length; count++) {
  if (extras[count].checked == true) {
    array.push(extras[count].value);
  }
}

if (array.length === 0) {
  array = ["None"];
}
```

Here it is in a working snippet:

```js
function calculatePrice() {
  var array = [];
  var extras = document.calc.extras;

  for (count = 0; count < extras.length; count++) {
    if (extras[count].checked == true) {
      array.push(extras[count].value);
    }
  }

  if (array.length === 0) {
    array = ["None"];
  }

  alert("(Including extras: " + array + ")");
}
```

```html
<form name="calc">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="40" id="col">
        <label for="extras">EXTRAS</label>
        <div class="left">
          <input type="checkbox" name="extras" id="ac" value="A/C">A/C (+$10)
          <input type="checkbox" name="extras" id="work" value="Working Brakes">Working Brakes (+$100)<br>
          <input type="checkbox" name="extras" id="cruise" value="Cruise Control">Cruise control (+$20)
          <input type="checkbox" name="extras" id="seat" value="Baby Seat">Baby Seat (+$30)<br>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="40" id="col">
        <input type="submit" onClick="calculatePrice();" value="Estimate Cost">
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>
```

Comment: I didn't think of taking it out of the loop. I thought by doing so, it would work out. Thank you so much and I appreciate the help :).